# What's the meaning of the number before the progress bar when tensorflow is training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-estimator

Could anyone tell me what's the meaning of  '10' and '49' in the following log of tensorflow?
Much Thanks

INFO:tensorflow:Started compiling

INFO:tensorflow:Finished compiling. Time elapsed: 5.899410247802734 secs

**10/10** [==============================] - 23s 2s/step - loss: 2.6726 - acc: 0.1459

**49/49** [==============================] - 108s 2s/step - loss: 2.3035 - acc: 0.2845 - val_loss: 2.6726 - val_acc: 0.1459

Epoch 2/100

**10/10** [==============================] - 1s 133ms/step - loss: 2.8799 - acc: 0.1693

**49/49** [==============================] - 17s 337ms/step - loss: 1.9664 - acc: 0.4042 - val_loss: 2.8799 - val_acc: 0.1693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 and 49 corresponds to the number of batches which your dataset has been divided into in each epoch.

For example, in your train dataset, there are totally 10000 images and your batch size is 64, then there will be totally `math.ceil(10000/64) = 157` batches possible in each epoch.

Comment: I'm very sorry I did not describe it in details. 

The 49 is from the log of https://github.com/appleyuchi/TPU_GPU_Code/blob/master/TPU运行Cifar10.ipynb.

And the total length of this datasets is 60000.